# how to return matches value using preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

please how do that ?

```
<?php
$string = '<inc="file.php">';
return preg_replace('#<inc\s*="\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\">#',include("$1"),$string);
?>
```

the output is return $1

i need to return include file.php

Comment: @hakre how exactly would that be helpful? I don't think it does replacing... anyway I wonder why would someone dislike this question since it was not marked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
return preg_replace('#<inc\s*="\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\">#','include("'.$1.'")',$string);
```

The second parameter should be a string.

Answer (score 4):

If you have PHP 5.3 or higher:

```
<?php
$string = '<inc="file.php">';
return preg_replace_callback('#<inc\s*="\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\">#', function($matches) {
    return include $matches[1];
}, $string);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but try using `preg_match` over preg_replace.

It gathers the matches into an array if you use it like shown:

`preg_match('#<inc\s*="\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\">#', $string, $matches);`

And then the matches are stored in the `$matches` array. You can then loop over them using `foreach`.

Comment: Why would he do that: **TLDR; *| don't want to do regexp 2x |*** ...full example: Imagine you have some data and one property of a data item is containing something extra that does not belong there in your particular context but you don't want to throw it away - it just belongs somewhere else in your context - so inefficiently you could 1. search for it and then 2. search for&replace it - you would do search twice(2x) which is unnecessary, that is the reason why would someone want this :-) Sidenote: If you think OP wants something different than what he/she asks for - ask in comment first ;)